# for which values of $\theta$.does this equation: $x_1^{\sin\theta}+\cdots+x_n^{\sin\theta}=1$ have rational solutions for all $n$?

Tags: diophantine-equations, rational-numbers

I'd surprised if this equation:$$x_1^{\sin\theta}+\cdots+x_n^{\sin\theta}=1 $$ have rational solutions for all $n$ and for all values of $\theta$.

My question here is: for which values of $\theta$ does this equation:
$$x_1^{\sin\theta}+\cdots+x_n^{\sin\theta}=1$$ have rational solutions for all $n$ ?

Thank you for any kind of help .

Comment: Please: It's $\displaystyle x_1^{\sin\theta}+\cdots+x_n^{\sin\theta}$, not $\displaystyle x_1^{sin\theta}+\cdots+x_n^{sin\theta}$.  I changed it. ${}\qquad{}$

Comment: @MichaelHardy, thank you very much for your edition and that what I meant

Comment: Is there any particular reason to have $\sin\theta$ in the exponent? Couldn't you just say $x_1^a+x_2^a+\ldots+x_n^a$ for $-1\leq a\leq 1$?

Comment: I would like to see the behavior of solution with theta paramater

Comment: You may wish to look for non-degenerate solutions instead, i.e. solutions such that $\sum_{i \in I} x_i^{\sin{\theta}} \neq 0$ for every non-empty subset $I$ of $\{1,\dotsc,n\}$. Every degenerate solution trivially gives rise to infinitely many other (degenerate) solutions. On the other hand, every degenerate solution can be obtained from a non-degenerate solution of $\sum_{j \in J} x_j^{\sin{\theta}} = 1$ for some non-empty subset $J$ of $\{1,\dotsc,n\}$.

Answer (score 1):

How about $x_1 = 1$, $x_2 = \ldots = x_n = 0$, as long as $\sin\theta > 0$ (I won't venture an opinion on the case $\sin\theta = 0$).